# Hubbard-Stratonovich tranformation and Saddle point equations for the SYK model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, greens-functions, self-energy

I have been trying to understand the derivation of saddle point equations of the Sachdev-Ye-Kitaev (SYK) model. Consider, for example, https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.05111. After decoupling the eight-fermion term in the replicated action (twice using Hubbard-Stratonovich fields $Q_{ab}$ and $P_{ab}$), the author finds the saddle point equations (Eq 21 in the reference above):
\begin{equation}
P_{ab}(\tau, \tau') = \langle c_a^{\dagger}(\tau)c_b(\tau')\rangle \hspace{0.5in} Q_{ab}(\tau, \tau') = J^2|P_{ab}(\tau, \tau')|^2.
\end{equation}
Then, $P_{ab}$ is identified with $\delta_{ab}G(\tau, \tau')$ where $G$ is the Green's function. But then, in Eq 24 in the reference, they jump to the conclusion that the self-energy of the Hamiltonian can be written as,
$$\Sigma(\tau) = -J^2G^2(\tau)G(-\tau).$$
How does this follow from the saddle point equations? I know of the diagrammatic approach to finding these same Schwinger-Dyson equations (melonic dominance in the large-$N$ limit), but there is a link I am missing in this alternative derivation. Can you shed some light on it, elaborate on the missing step perhaps? Thanks for your help.